# Swap two strings 2 by 2 in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I've go a string made in this way.

"AABBCCDD....." grouped by 4 with variable lenght.

I need a method that swap that 2 by two the chars in this string

```
def swap2_by_2( string )
???
end
```

If the input is AABBCCDD the output will be BBAADDCC

Thanks, i'm very noob in ruby.

Edit: my mistake, a more comprhensive example may be.. Input: ABCDEFGH -> CDABGHEF

Comment: What do you mean by "grouped by 4"? It is not clear. The format of the string is not clear. Does the string always consists of substrings that are length two and consist of the same character?

Comment: ABCD ->BADC? this sounds like a big endian / little indean conversion (Endianness) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness]; can it be possible, that you want that conversation, and started already with 'i make a string of it'?

Comment: sry. it should have been [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what the OP is trying to do, but if it is to flip the first and the second characters with the third and fourth characters for every four characters, then the example that the OP showed is highly misleading and inappropriate (It should have been `"ABCD..."` instead of `"AABB..."`). In that case, a solution would be:

```
string.gsub(/(..)(..)/, '\2\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about your question, an interpreting the "ABCDEF", I am sure, that you are looking for pack / unpack in Ruby: I found a good page here [How to change bit order in Ruby](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/07/20/ruby-pack-unpack.html)

Answer (score 0):

And here are two a non-regexp versions:

```
p 'AABBCCDD'.chars
  .each_slice(2)
  .each_slice(2)
  .map(&:reverse)
  .join

#=> "BBAADDCC"

# or

'AABBCCDD'.chars
  .each_slice(4)
  .map{|x| x.rotate(2)}
  .join
```